# Locked excel sheet that isn't open

Tags: windows, excel, locked

I am trying to open a locked excel sheet. The warning says it is locked because it is being used by "AN Other".

This person does not have the sheet open, does not have any excel applications open, does not have any excel based tasks running in the task list and has tried the good old "turning it off and on again".

Neither of us can save onto this filename, change it in windows explorer or delete the file.

We have "saved as" another name but really need the original name. I looked at a few forums and they suggest this is an excel/windows bug.

Am using excel 2010 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get in touch with your IT support.

In a company network, a file will be locked for other users when somebody edits it. It can happen sometimes that the file does not get released (unlocked) when the user closes it. Your IT Support people need to unlock the file, so you can edit it again.